# Assigning Write-Host value to a Variable - Powershell

Tags: powershell

I have a piece of code whereby someone enters a comma seperated string as a parameter like so:

```
[string[]] $ipAddressList = "123.113.331.31, 33.33.23.41,22.323.233.14"

        foreach($ipAddress in $ipAddressList.Split(",").Trim())
        {   
            Write-Host "1|${ipAddress}|" -NoNewline
        }
```

This is displaying data the exact way I want in this format:  1|123.113.331.31|1|33.33.23.41|1|22.323.233.14| (this is used for an internal program)

How do I assign this value returned to me into a variable as I need to insert it into a configuration file?

Thanks
Rob

Comment: DO NOT use `Write-Host` for anything other than what it is designed for - display on-screen. [*grin*] yes, there are workarounds, but they are graceless AND unneeded. assign it to a $Var and send that to wherever you want it to go. ///// also, take a look at the `-f` string format operator OR using `$Collection -join '|'`.

Answer (score 3):

`Write-Host` means "output to the screen". A good rule of thumb is that you almost never want to use `Write-Host` because it's output cannot be assigned to anything. It really means *output to the screen*. The return value of the command is, as you have probably discovered, no output.

You can solve your problem like so:

On PowerShell 7:

```
$MyInput = "123.113.331.31, 33.33.23.41,22.323.233.14"

$MyOutput = $MyInput.Split(',').Trim() | ForEach-Object { "1|$_|" } | Join-String
```

On PowerShell 5 or earlier:

```
$MyInput = "123.113.331.31, 33.33.23.41,22.323.233.14"

$MyOutput = -join $($MyInput.Split(',').Trim() | ForEach-Object { "1|$_|" })
```

Comment: Great, thanks for that.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the read-host command to ask the user for input.

`$ipAddressList= Read-Host "Please enter the IP Address list"`

More information from the Microsoft documentation,

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/read-host?view=powershell-7.1